# MAGENTO: How to display waringns like errors?

Tags: magento

My errors/local.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <skin>default</skin>
    <report>
        <action>print</action>
        <subject>Store Debug Information</subject>
        <email_address></email_address>
        <trash>trash</trash>
    </report>
</config>
```

Is it possible to display warning in browser?

PS:
I can see errors in browser when they are. 
But I would like to see warnings also, not just in log file.

Comment: It's unclear what's being asked here, making it impossible to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable developer mode. In Magento > 1.3 you need only set an environment variable (MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE) as this is evaluated in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can uncomment errors settings in index.php

Comment: Yes, I've done it at first.
Varien_Profiler::enable();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);