# Magento crop image?

Tags: image, magento, crop

I found this: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Image/Varien_Image.html#crop

But I'm not sure if this is deprecated or something because when I tried this:

```
echo rawurlencode($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->setWatermarkImageOpacity(0)->crop(10, 20, 30, 40)->resize(300, null))
```

It doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::crop() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/xxxxx/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

So is the crop() method actually usable at all? If it is, how can I use it to crop (not to be confused with resize) the product images of Magento? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's available in 1.6 version as well. I think you had a mistaken in the code, check again. `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')` returns a `Varien_Image` instance, when in fact there are two intermediate classes involved:
`Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image`.

The `catalog/image` helper is a mess, even though it has been cleaned up a bit in recent versions (e.g. no more private methods). Still, some getters still are protected without there being a real need for it.
Here is my workaround:

```
/* @var $imageHelper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image */
// Initialize the image helper
$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
        ->constrainOnly(true)
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->keepFrame(false)
        ->setWatermarkImageOpacity(0);

// Get the catalog/product_image instance
/* @var $imageModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image */
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($imageHelper);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('_model');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$imageModel = $property->getValue($imageHelper);

// Initialize the missing values on the image model
// Usually done in Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::__toString()
if (! $imageModel->isCached())
{
    $getWatermarkMethod = $reflection->getMethod('getWatermark');
    $getWatermarkMethod->setAccessible(true);
    $imageModel->setBaseFile($_product->getImage())
        ->resize()
        ->setWatermark($getWatermarkMethod->invoke($imageHelper));

    // Crop the image using the image processor
    // $imageModel->getImageProcessor() returns a Varien_Image instance
    $imageModel->getImageProcessor()->crop(10, 20, 30, 40);

    // Generate the image according to the set parameters and
    // get the URL while bypassing the helper to avoid reinitialization
    $url = $imageModel->saveFile()->getUrl();
}
echo $url . "\n";
```

It would be easier to use the `catalog/product_image` model or `Varien_Image` directly, but this way all the Magento watermark settings still are applied.
Either way isn't clean.
I hope the getters on the helper are made public in future releases.

Comment: Hi Vinai, Thanks for your detailed answer. However, this line "$property->setAccessible(true);" seems to be causing the page rendering to stop, leaving half page blank without any error messages. I tried to get rid of it and it's this error: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1493431759

Comment: You need to enable the developer mode. You can set the environment variable MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE to enable displaying of error messages, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8296059/485589

Comment: Awesome, thanks Vinai. It was this error: Fatal error<b>:  Call to undefined method ReflectionProperty::setAccessible() in <b>/home/xxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/xxxx/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
Deleting the setAccessible() line would give another error: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 967394775

Comment: Your PHP version probably is < 5.3, for `ReflectionProperty::setAccessible()` to exist (see http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php). There are workarounds for older PHP versions in the comments.

Comment: i have added this code it is make image resize fix height and width like 212*212 and also original image not appear and got default magento place holder image as resized.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the alternative method ( credits from Onlinebizsoft.com )
The following code first looking the image that available in the /resize directory, if it's not there, doing rest of things.

```
// actual path of image
$_imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."myimage".DS.$post->getThumbnail();

// path of the resized image to be saved
// here, the resized image is saved in media/resized folder
$imageResized =  Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."myimage".DS."resized".DS.$post->getThumbnail();

// resize image only if the image file exists and the resized image file doesn't exist
// the image is resized proportionally with the width/height 135px
if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($_imageUrl)) :
    $imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
    $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
    $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
    $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
    $imageObj->resize(135, 135);
    $imageObj->save($imageResized);
endif;
```

Check the website [Resize - Scale Crop images](http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/magento-resize-image-how-to-and-parameter/)

Comment: I think you want to add an underscore at the top for the $imageUrl to be $_imageUrl to match the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Varien_Image class ?

```
$image = new Varien_Image($img);
$cropped = $image->crop();
```

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be using auto-generated path with random directory names like ->resize() is doing. I mean, if there are tens of thousands of images with some identical file names, it'd be hard to not overwriting existing ones, because I have to manually provide the resulted image file name.